# Porting php 5.4 to 5.3

Tags: php, backwards-compatibility

Is there any automation tool for converting a php 5.4 script back to 5.3? Mostly there are new style arrays causing problems.

This:

```
<?php
$x = [1, 2, 3];
$y = [
  'a' => [1,2],
  'b' => 'c',
];
function ff($x = []) { ...}
```

Should be converted to this:

```
<?php
$x = array(1, 2, 3);
$y = array(
  'a' => array(1,2),
  'b' => 'c',
);
function ff($x = array()) { ...}
```

Comment: I checked around, didn't see anything. Probably can use a perl/sed/awk script to change `(\W)\[(.*)\](\W)` to `\1array (\2)\3`, though you would need to handle beginning and ending of line specially with that regex.  I suppose you could also write a quick script using PHP 5.4 `token_get_all` looking for a `T_ARRAY` ,but that would likely heavily reformat your code.

Comment: Maybe you could turn around this script: https://github.com/thomasbachem/php-short-array-syntax-converter

Comment: @bishop token_get_all does not treat '[' and ']' as tokens :|

Comment: @DanLee I'll try and if it worked I'll post it here.

Comment: I'll be, [you're right](http://3v4l.org/RNtpP).  That looks like a PHP bug to me.

Comment: [Opened a bug report on this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66649).

Comment: An assignment operator `=` followed by a square bracket `[` should be a sufficient check. (Skipping whitespaces of course)

Comment: You might take a look at https://github.com/igorw/galapagos. However that will reformat your entire code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a tool to convert your codebase from PHP 5.4+ to PHP 5.3, such as: http://github.com/endel/php-code-downgrade/

This tool will read all your files and rewrite code using PHP 5.3 standards, even for your composer dependencies.

The ideal scenario is to write code compatible with your production server, but sometimes it is not possible to know it by antecedence, so this tool may do the job for you.

The advantages of using this is that you can write modern code without worrying about legacy PHP version support.

Comment: Just want to note the install steps, as seems not yet in github: 1. clone the repository `git clone https://github.com/endel/php-code-downgrade.git && cd php-code-downgrade` 2. install composer dependencies `composer install`

Comment: It should also be made clear that php-code-downgrader converts the files _in place_, so make sure to run it against a copy of your repo. `php php-code-downgrade <path to copy of repo>` (or just `./php-code-downgrade <path to copy>` if you're on a nix-ish OS and have php in your path).